# How to call a class component with a variabel?

Tags: reactjs

I have this function, with a headline. How can I call something like:

**<LayerEditPost test={"It works!"} />** so that my **{this.state.test}** changes?

In functional components, I can pass properties to call my components, but it does not work with class components ( Property 'test' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}>)

I am not sure where I have to declare my variable so that I am able to receive a value from the component call.

```
export class LayerEditPost extends React.Component<{}, {test: string, open: boolean}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { open: false, test: "hi" };
        this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this);
    }

    toggleDrawer(e) {
        console.log("click", e);
        this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <IconLink icon={object___pencil} iconVariant={"solid"} onClick={this.toggleDrawer}></IconLink>
                <Layer
                    layout={"right-75"}
                    closeLinkLabel={"Back to Administration"}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onCloseClick={this.toggleDrawer}
                    htmlAttrs={{
                        "aria-labelledby": "layerLeftLabel",
                        "aria-describedby": "layerLeftDescription",
                    }}
                >
                    <H2 id="layerLeftLabel">Edit Post</H2>
                    <H2>{this.state.test}</H2> <- I want to call LayerEditPost with a variable to change "test"
                </Layer>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`React.Component<{}, {test: string, open: boolean}>`](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/class_components) definition at the first line, you have two generic types: The second one is the type for your state and the first one (`{}`) for the properties you are looking for.

You can move your `test: string` definition to the first object type, so that your definition becomes

```
export class LayerEditPost extends React.Component<{test: string}, {open: boolean}> { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can access the passed property using `this.props.test`:

```
export class LayerEditPost extends React.Component<{test: string}, {open: boolean}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {/* Other stuff ... */}
                <H2>{this.props.test}</H2> <- I want to call LayerEditPost with a variable to change "test"
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I had to delete "test: hi" in my states. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped you! You can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to indicate it worked for you

Comment: You had to remove `test` from your state, because you removed it from the type definition as well. If you need it (for any reason), you can add it again in the 2nd state definition as before.